# Undefined array key 0 - Laravel custom ID

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to generate custom id using the Laravel [Custom](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-custom-id-generator?fbclid=IwAR3nvoPrIF2wgnu3RLYI9F7VH75DZ-ZpfM2r4JeGfSxepp-hWb0H7Gl_OKs) ID package but I am getting Undefined array key 0. I followed the provide code, and i don't why i am getting this error, i tried both in the controller and the model. When i add 'field' => 'name', it works but generates the same code, by default it should use the id column but that gives me the error.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'description', 'product_category_id', 'price', 'stock', 'stock_defective', 'barcode', 'barcodeID',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory', 'product_category_id')->withTrashed();
    }

    public function solds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SoldProduct');
    }

    public function receiveds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ReceivedProduct');
    }

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function (Product $model) {  
            $model->barcodeID = IdGenerator::generate(['table'=>'products', 'length'=> 4, 'prefix'=>date('y') ]);
        });
    }
    
}
```

the database:

```
$table->unsignedinteger('barcodeID')->nullable();
```

any help?

so now, i am using the name field as the id field giving me an error

```
 public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function (Product $model) {  
        $model->barcodeID = IdGenerator::generate(['table'=>'products', 'field' => 'name', 'length'=> 6, 'prefix'=> date('my') ]);
    });
}
```

but it doesn't output unique code, it output the same code. why? i want it to increment the code as 082101, 082102...etc

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the saving() model event yet?  Also, shouldn't the field you're targeting be barcodeID?

```php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::saving(function (Product $model) {  
        $model->barcodeID = IdGenerator::generate(['table'=>'products', 'field' => 'barcodeID', 'length'=> 6, 'prefix'=> date('my') ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: i have the id as primary key table->bigIncrements('id');
but when i use the id in the IdGenerator it gives me the array key 0

Comment: I added an updated answer above, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with MySQL version 8. Recent package updates solved the issue. Update to [v1.1.0](https://github.com/haruncpi/laravel-id-generator/releases/tag/v1.1.0)